# How can I pass multiple command parameters to a button WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding

To set up the context :

I have a datagrid with multiple data types inside. For each type, I have a custom data template for the details to fit my data. In the details, I have a little form with a text box and 2 buttons. The objective is to get the data of my row and the content of my text box when I click the buttons.

Curently, I have created a class with those parameters and I am trying to pass this class to my command parameter this way :

```xml
<Button Content="Validate" Width="70" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource btnVmValidateReserved}, Path=ButtonValidateReservedCommand}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <model:ButtonValidateReservedCommandArgs Item="{Binding Data}" Message="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=umMasterComment}"/>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Here is my class :

```cs
public class ButtonValidateReservedCommandArgs : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(object), typeof(ButtonValidateReservedCommandArgs));
    public object Item
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonValidateReservedCommandArgs));
    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue (MessageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

When I try with bindings, I always have null as a result. But when I try to do it with a random text, it works.

Also, when i try to do it this way it works :

```xml
<Button Content="Validate" Width="70" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource btnVmValidateReserved}, Path=ButtonValidateReservedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Data}"/>
```

However, I need my 2 arguments and I can’t figure out to do it.

If you have any idea to have a working binding, or even another solution to pass my 2 arguments, I’ll take it .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass a multiple parameters you can do it this way:

```
<Button Command="{Binding YourCommand">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CloneMultiConverter}">
             <Binding Path="Argument1"/>
             <Binding Path="Argument2"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>  

public class CloneMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Clone();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}  

private void YourCommand(object parameter)
{
    var values = (object[])parameter;
    var firstArgument = (argumentType)values[0];
    var secondArgument = (argumentType)values[1];
}
```